# Rails path gives me no route matches, but I don't understand why

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I have a very simple I think layout. My config routes is:

```
  resources :webcomics
  match '/webcomics/first' => 'webcomics#first', :as => :first
  match '/webcomics/random' => 'webcomics#random', :as => :random
  match '/webcomics/latest' => 'webcomics#latest', :as => :latest
```

Controller:

```
  def show
    @webcomic = Webcomic.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @webcomic }
    end
  end

  def first
    @webcomic = Webcomic.order("created_at ASC").first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render 'show'}
      format.json { render json: @webcomic }
    end
  end
```

navigation bar:

```
<%= link_to first_webcomics_path, :rel => "tooltip", :title => "first comic" do %>
              formatting in here
        <% end %>
```

when I click on this link, it sends me to the right path /webcomics/first, BUT it gives me the error

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"webcomics"}
```

I am breaking my head how is it going to 'EDIT', and no matter this message is totally wrong, I do have edit, but why does it try to go to action edit.

```
def edit
    @webcomic = Webcomic.find(params[:id])
end
```

Results of rake routes:

```
 first_webcomics GET    /webcomics/first(.:format)    webcomics#first
latest_webcomics GET    /webcomics/latest(.:format)   webcomics#latest
random_webcomics GET    /webcomics/random(.:format)   webcomics#random
       webcomics GET    /webcomics(.:format)          webcomics#index
                 POST   /webcomics(.:format)          webcomics#create
    new_webcomic GET    /webcomics/new(.:format)      webcomics#new
   edit_webcomic GET    /webcomics/:id/edit(.:format) webcomics#edit
        webcomic GET    /webcomics/:id(.:format)      webcomics#show
                 PUT    /webcomics/:id(.:format)      webcomics#update
                 DELETE /webcomics/:id(.:format)      webcomics#destroy
            root        /                             webcomics#index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routing is in order; put the `match`es above the `resources`.

That said, I'd consider [adding those routes as RESTful actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) instead:

```
resources :webcomics
  collection do
    get 'first'
    get 'random'
    get 'latest'
  end
end
```

IMO this is a bit cleaner, and happens to fit reasonably well.

---

The issue is because of your edit link in the `show` template. Edit links require an object to 
edit:

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_webcomic_path(@webcomic) %>
```

Comment: I did it this way too - still getting the same error. also wouldn't i get a different error if the problem was the order?

Comment: @StanM No; with the `match` it's trying to interpret the RESTful action name as the ID. Why it says there's no `edit` method I'm not sure, because you say there is one. Please add the results of running `rake routes` to your question.

Comment: added to the original post

Comment: @StanM Look at your routes; what are you currently using for your path helper? What is your current routes file for the webcomics?

Comment: sorry I ran the routes after making the change to the way it was before - this still didnt help (also updated to the new rake routes)

Comment: @StanM And you restarted the server? Did you try adding some link text as the first param?

Comment: yes sir, I have no clue what I am missing. In case it would help - it's current running on http://23.22.30.40/

Comment: @StanM What is your current routes.rb for this resource? Can you put the project on github along with its .rvmrc file or whatever you're using?

Comment: https://github.com/stanlx/comic where do I find my rvmrc file (or whatever the equivalent would be)?

Comment: @StanM In your project? Apparently you're not using anything to manage Ruby/gem versions, though.

Comment: @StanM Fixed; created pull request and explained in answer.

Comment: Thank you! works great now, much appreciated. I don't understand why with I would get that specific error when trying to click on a different link

Comment: when I clicked on the page from the index, how come did it render fine? (same for 'previous' and 'next' buttons)

Comment: @StanM Don't know, I'd have to look in to it.

Answer (score 3):

Put those three `match` rules above the `resources` line like that:

```
match '/webcomics/first' => 'webcomics#first', :as => :first
match '/webcomics/random' => 'webcomics#random', :as => :random
match '/webcomics/latest' => 'webcomics#latest', :as => :latest
resources :webcomics
```

The reason is explained in [Ruby Guides: Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions):

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action’s
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To
>   fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is
>   matched first.